# Validate the original certificate template

Tags: certificate, template

I need to verify from what template was copied a certificate template y have searched in all the tabs for info but i have found anything about what was the original certificate template.

**the template display name have been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't know this certainly, because this information is not stored anywhere. Though, if there are few modifications, you can find a set of possible source templates that could be used for duplication. Just compare template settings (including CSP information, extensions, request handling, subject name source).

In addition, you can check template minor version. When you duplicate template, new template's minor version is +1 of the source. That is, if original template had version 100.5, then duplicate template will have version 100.6. Note that each time you modify template, its minor number is increased. This may provide additional hints, but yet -- not certainly.